# How to pull data without calling api again

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, object

I have campaignsId on `getAllCampaigns` api, i have to grab stats from `getAllStats` api, but i don't want to call `getAllCampiagns` again in `getAllStats` api to iterate it, what i'm trying is :

```
const collectCampaigns = async () => {

    let campaigns = await getAllCampaigns()

    const allData = campaigns.data.data.map((campaign, index) => ({
        ...campaign,
        ...getAllStats(campaign)
    }))
```

Api helper for stats is :

```
exports.getAllStats = async (data) => {
    try {
        console.log(data)
            return await Promise.all(data.map(async (i) => await (
                await axios.get(`https://api.truepush.com/api/v1/campaignStats/${i.campaignId}`, config)
            )))

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

console.log on data gives :

```
{
  campaignId: '6008438eef57d4cf19772af1',
  campaignTitle: 'API',
  campaignStatus: 'completed'
},
{
  campaignId: '6008438eef57d4cf19772af2',
  campaignTitle: 'API',
  campaignStatus: 'completed'
}
```

Error while collecting stats :

```
TypeError: data.map is not a function
```

How do i solve this problem and get `getAllCampaigns` and `getAllStats` data inside alldata.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that **Objects**, `{ }` in JavaScript does not have the method `.map()`. It's only for Arrays, `[ ]`.

So in order for your code to work change `data.map()` to something like `data.campaign.map()` assuming campaign is an array that you can iterate upon and get all the required data that you want.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: The error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" will be encountered if there is an error in the "this.props.data" or there is no props.data array.

Comment: Or you try putting "data" into a pair of square brackets (i.e. [data])